# Tell if IntPtr points to managed or unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, .net, interop, intptr

I'm using a wrapped C-library in C# and need to convert an image from that library to a Bitmap and back, but **without** copying the pixel buffer.

Converting to a Bitmap was simple:

```
Bitmap WrapAsBitmap(CImage image)
{
    return new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, image.BytesPerLine, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, image.Data);
}
```

By just passing in the original pixel buffer (`image.Data`) to the `Bitmap` constructor, no copy is needed. For doing the opposite, I need to call `LockBits` and `UnlockBits` to get access to the `IntPtr` of the original pixel buffer:

```
CImage WrapAsCImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var image = new CImage(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, data.Stride * 3, data.Scan0);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
    return image;
}
```

Now, as you can see, if `data.Scan0` is in managed memory, this is actually a dangerous approach as the bits are 'unlocked' before the newly constructed `image` will be used. If `bitmap` was constructed from the `WrapAsBitmap` method, then there is no problem as `data.Scan0` points to unmanaged memory which will not be moved by .NET. Therefore, I want to build in a safety check that checks the location (managed/unmanaged) of the `data.Scan0` pointer.

An other solution I was thinking of was to inherit from the `Bitmap` class and keep track of the original pointer `image.Data` along with the `Bitmap`, but the `Bitmap` class is sealed, so I'm out of luck.

**In short:** any ideas how to detect the location (managed/unmanaged) of an `IntPtr`?

Comment: What is `CImage` here?

Comment: A wrapper class that wraps an image coming from the C-library. The only relevant members of this class are shown in the `WrapAsBitmap` method

Comment: It it would be possible (I don't know), you have another problem here: CImage -> WrapAsBitmap -> WrapAsCImage -> CImage, now you have two CImage instances pointing to the same memory. Maybe you need to copy the memory in WrapAsCImage?

Comment: @AlexFarber I'm aware of that, but that is not a problem here

Comment: Stupid suggestion: what about using Image.Tag property? Not generic, but may work if used correctly.

Comment: I thought about that too, but really didn't want to go that road :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no scenario where that IntPtr is *ever* going to point to managed memory.  Not when the image data was generated by C code of course.  Not when it was generated by Bitmap either, GDI+ is unmanaged code.  You can reason this through by yourself, you can only ever obtain an IntPtr for managed memory by pinning it.  GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().  A hard requirement to prevent the garbage collector from invalidating the pointer when it compacts the heap.  Nowhere do you see a documented need to pin.

There is no point in implementing the test.

You *do* have the rock-hard requirement to keep that IntPtr valid for the lifetime of the Bitmap wrapper.  Up to the point where you call its Dispose() method.  You cannot make this automagic, other than by encapsulating the Bitmap object in a class that implements IDisposable itself.  Not doing so causes very ugly mis-behavior, you only get an AccessViolationException when you're lucky.  A corrupted bitmap with random pixel content is the normal failure mode.

If you can't implement that guarantee then you should *not* do this and copy the bitmap data instead.  It is not hard to implement, just not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap` class is actually just a managed wrapper for a GDI+ Bitmap object. Since that object does not operate on a fixed buffer which is exposed to user code, nor is that buffer guaranteed to be in a particular format, you will not be able to perform the operation you have described.

In other words, without restricting your problem space from what you have asked, there will definitely be cases where buffer copying is required.

Comment: Hmm it does not I think, see [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14(v=vs.110).aspx) and also the remark: The caller is responsible for allocating and freeing the block of memory specified by the scan0 parameter. However, the memory should not be released until the related Bitmap is released.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit The documentation for the underlying GDI+ method that it uses suggests that the buffer is copied: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536315.aspx